# Запретить доступ к изображениям на моем сайте для других приложений

Tags: android, изображения, веб-сервер, права-доступа

Есть приложение для Андроида которое скачивает изображения с моего сайта и устанавливает их в качестве обоев.

Существует гипотетическая вероятность, что кто-либо "залезет" в приложение, узнает ссылку и вставит в свое приложение, или вообще сделает клон моего приложения, что не особо радует.

На данном этапе развития приложения этот вопрос мало волнует, так как приложение малопопулярное, но хочется думать и о позитивной перспективе, да и вообще это интересно с академической точки зрения.

Подскажите какие существуют практики, если не защиты то хотя бы затруднения использования данного сценария. Можно ли это как-то отслеживать по логам `Apache`'а?

Comment: ну сами подумайте, вам нужен такой секрет, который никто не знает кроме вас и вашего приложения. При этом вы прекрасно понимаете, что в ваше приложение можно "залезть" и подсмотреть все секреты

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову - обслуживать запросы на картинки не непосредственно апачем, а каким-либо приложением на стороне сервера, позволяя забирать картинки только авторизованным на сервере пользователям.

Comment: На сервере определить хорошо подделанный запрос невозможно. Единственный относительно надёжный механизм защиты - это авторизация, но это привязка к юзеру, а не к приложению. От взлома приложения нет надёжной защиты, можно лишь усложнить. Не писать урлы и ключи в открытом виде - шифровать, дробить на части, запутывать инициализацию переменных, в которых они будут храниться. Но все секреты можно подсмотреть и не ломая аппу прослушиванием трафика - кастомный сертификат с проверкой его на сервере может усложнить жизнь взломщику, но опять же его нужно спрятать получше в самом приложении.

Comment: @woesss Оформите как ответ я приму.